# conflict between jquery.include & jquery 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.8

```
if(jQuery.browser.mozilla||jQuery.browser.opera)document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",jQuery.ready,!1),document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){jQuery.ready()},!1);jQuery.event.remove(window,"load",jQuery.ready);jQuery.event.add(window,"load",function(){jQuery.ready()});
jQuery.extend({includeStates:{},include:function(c,a,d){typeof a!="function"&&!d&&(d=a,a=null);c=c.replace("\n","");jQuery.includeStates[c]=!1;var b=document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.onload=function(){jQuery.includeStates[c]=!0;a&&a.call(b)};b.onreadystatechange=function(){this.readyState!="complete"&&this.readyState!="loaded"||(jQuery.includeStates[c]=!0,a&&a.call(b))};b.src=c;d?(d.constructor!=Array&&(d=[d]),setTimeout(function(){var a=!0;jQuery.each(d,function(c,b){if(!b())return a=
!1});a?document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(b):setTimeout(arguments.callee,10)},10)):document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(b);return function(){return jQuery.includeStates[c]}},readyOld:jQuery.ready,ready:function(){jQuery.isReady||(imReady=!0,jQuery.each(jQuery.includeStates,function(c,a){if(!a)return imReady=!1}),imReady?jQuery.readyOld.apply(jQuery,arguments):setTimeout(arguments.callee,10))}});

jQuery.noConflict();
```

it's related with loading images even it was loaded into cache. In version 1.7.2 everything was okay, but now i Have a problem with promises()

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){jQuery.isReady||(imReady=!0,jQuery.each(jQuery.includeStates,function(c,a){if(!a)return imReady=!1}),imReady?jQuery.readyOld.apply(jQuery,arguments):setTimeout(arguments.callee,10))} has no method 'promise'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using "jQuery.browser" ... it has been deprecated in Jquery 1.8